# Setters and getters with composition in Java

Tags: java, oop, composition

I have a doubt regarding setters and getters in Java when it gets to using composition instead of inheritance. 
This doubt came when I was solving a college assignment.

Let's say that I have 2 classes: car and battery. Battery has 3 variables (var1, var2, var3) with the getters and setters.

The car class is something like this:

```
public class Car {
  private String color;
  private String model;
  private Battery battery;

  public Car(String color, String model, Battery battery) {
    this.color = color;
    this.model = model;
    this.Battery = new Battery(battery);
  }

  public getBattery() {
    return new Battery(battery);
  }

  public void setBattery(Battery battery) {
    this.battery = new Battery(battery.getVar1(), battery.getVar2(), battery.getVar3());
    //or this.battery = battery;
  }
```

I know the reasoning for the getter method (since it's related with the references for the object), but what about the setter method?
I tried looking up in the web along with a Java course at Udemy (from Tim Buchalka), but I haven't seen this addressed.

Can someone help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: please clarify your question its not clear

Comment: I assume that for the setter method it's the same reason. However I wouldn't recommend you to do such an implementation, as it's not straight forward that the instance is copied (and it's not a common practise as well).

Comment: @Nithin my doubt about the setter is that everytime I see one setter of an object in examples in the web it's always something like "this.battery = battery". 
But on my the pdf file of this college subject, the examples over there are like the one that I put.

I get that you're redefining the 3 variables of the object, but my doubt is whether it's better to do the way I wrote because of the references stuff, or if there's other reason (like good practice or whatever).

Comment: @Lenon yes, that's the point. On this college subject I have to do it that way, or else my grades will be a bit lower. I just wanted to 100% understand the reasoning, considering I haven't seen such an implementation anywhere on the internet.

Comment: Take a look at [immutability](https://www.baeldung.com/java-immutable-object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the three methods in the `Car` class is making a [defensive copy](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31551&seqNum=2) of the `Battery`. This prevents any other object outside of the `Car` from changing the `Battery` that is inside the `Car`, because no other object will have a reference to that specific `Battery` instance (since it is always copied).

The idiom `new Battery(battery)` is known as a *copy constructor* because it utilizes a constructor to clone an object. It is a common attribute of defensive copying.

Comment: Thank you! I was getting trouble getting it, and now I understand it. Moreover, I didn't know that concept (defensive copying), which I'm now going to study.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the way it’s implemented, I disagree with the format. Better practice is to write this.battery = battery and leave it at that (rather than create a new object and assign its variables as done in the question).

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks odd, in places, and I've changed it to what I'd expect it to look like:

```
public class Car {
  private String color;
  private String model;
  private Battery battery;

  public Car(String color, String model, Battery battery) {
    this.color = color;
    this.model = model;

    //Now, we're setting Car.battery to the battery that you passed in. 
    //Previously, you were passing the battery instance back into the Battery constructor.
    this.battery = battery;
    //this.battery = new Battery(battery); 
  }

  public getBattery() {
    //We want to return the battery we have above, not a new battery
    return battery;
    //return new Battery(battery);
  }

  public void setBattery(Battery battery) {
    //You wouldn't do this. Just use the line you've commented out.
    //No need to remake a new Battery object when you already have one passed in.

    this.battery = new Battery(battery.getVar1(), battery.getVar2(), battery.getVar3());
    //or this.battery = battery;
  }
```

What is the point of the setter method? Its to set/change the value of battery in the car instance, after you have already constructed the car. Whereas you'd use the constructor to set the battery DURING construction.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a copy of battery and store it then you are making the car class immune to mutation.

Mutation means, suppose you store the battery object given as input in setter method and then somewhere down the line you make a change to the same battery object then you are inadvertently changing the battery object in the previously created car class as well which may not be intended as part of that change, hence to avoid such issues you can use this approach so that the value of battery object in car is going to change only through the setter method or through the constructor.

I hope this helps you understand why they want that extra object creation in setter method

Comment: Thank you! That was it, I was having trouble getting this.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you are intend to exhibit composition in Java you should not have a getter to the component. Let's explain with an example. Say class A is composed of B. Class A (the composed) will have a private field of type B (the component). There will not be a getter to get B . If you need to access any property/ functionality of B, there should be a method of A which wraps a call to the component B's property/method.

Answer (score -1):

The general rule of thumb when you have private objects (in this case, Battery) as attributes in your class, is that you need getters and setters.  The getters and setters need to return a copy of the private object, so that you don't violate information hiding.  Otherwise, you could do something like this:

```
Car c1 = new Car(...);
...
Battery b1 = new Battery(var1, var2, var3);
c1.setBattery(b1);  // if setBattery doesn't make a copy, 
                    // then the private variable battery in c1 
                    // is the same reference as b1

b1.changeOneOfTheValues(); // I change b1, and now my private variable 
                           // in c1 is also changed!
```

Comment: For my 10+ years professional experience, I have never seen such an implementation. Consider taking a look at https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter

Comment: @lenon Not sure how promoting Project Lombok remotely addresses anything the original poster asked.  Original question wanted to know why the setter made a copy instead of just doing this.battery = battery.

Comment: This library is extremely popular, and I don't think they need my promotion, I have just used them as an example for the common practise (because they are so popular).